# MSSQL: Back dating from current year to the specified year and month.

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder3.0

I am currently working on a report in which I need to query all revenue generated across years for a specified month. For example: Year: 2009, Month: February.

So I need to start from 2014 and back date until 2009 but only get data for the month of February (accounting for the leap days as well).

Any ideas how I can accomplish this. I don't know how to add these date specific parameters to the existing query.

Comment: Would help if you post the "existing query".

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @StartYear AS INT = 2009 -- would be a parameter
DECLARE @Month AS INT = 2   -- would be a parameter

SELECT *
FROM   dbo.SomeTable s
WHERE  DATEPART(MONTH, s.TheDate) = @Month
       AND DATEPART(YEAR, s.TheDate) >= @StartYear
```